# Getting issue while Executing simple Appium Script from eclipse using Android Emulator , Please help me identify the issue

Tags: java, android-emulator, appium, appium-android

Having 2 files and  added jar files is added as Snapshot, my appium server is running fine showing me 200 response and on android emulator app is opening but not able to click any thing   [Java Build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anPK4.png) and appium server logs as snapshot   [Appium Server Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gob50.png), node version:v14.16.1, npm version:6.14.12, jave version: jdk-16_windows-x64_bin,Android studio 3.4.2 &Appium server:1.21.0
"ApiDemos-debug.apk" demo app used,
//base file 1 content:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Base {

    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File f= new File("src");
    File fs= new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");  
DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "appium");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"uiautomator2");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver= new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
return driver ;
    }

}
```

//Basics file 2 content:

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class Basics extends Base{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.widget.TextView)[8]").click();
    //driver.wait(2000);
    //driver.findElementsByClassName("//android.widget.TextView").get(8).click();
    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Preference\")").click();
    
}
```

}

Now when running from eclipse the basics file 2 getting following issue, even in basic file with the commented lines also getting similar failure response:

May 09, 2021 11:00:15 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
at io.appium.java_client.internal.ElementMap.getElementClass(ElementMap.java:77)
at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.newRemoteWebElement(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter.apply(JsonToWebElementConverter.java:55)
at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.apply(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:63)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.FindsByAndroidUIAutomator.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(FindsByAndroidUIAutomator.java:38)
at Basics.main(Basics.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)

Comment: I have added the images of my java build path and Appium server logs in the starting few lines, plz check those to  get better understanding

Answer (score 0):

The error message reads:

> Caused by: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`: `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtil`

Therefore you may want to add [Apache Commons Lang 3.x](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3) to debug builds:

```
debugImplementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0"
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin Zeitler for Quick reply , i actually have used the "org.apache.commons.lang3" jar file in my javabuildpath after checking your message but still Got that issue . Then read a little more and Checked to know that i used wrong jar file in javaBuildpath so i was facing that issue.

Answer (score 0):

**For other who has faced the same issue let me explain the steps:**

1. open "[Apache website to download commons-lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi)" > download: commons-lang3-3.12.0-bin.zip under Apache Commons Lang 3.12.0 (Java 8+)>Binaries
2. unzip the folder and copy "commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar" file only , other jar files not needed. Navigate to similar path in your system : "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext"  and paste the above jar
3. open eclipse> right click on project > properties> java build path> libraries> Add external jars...> select "commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar" from the download folder> apply and close
4. add "import org.apache.commons.*;" at top of the .java file and save> run
5. Now run your project hopefully that issue is solved if not please let me know. Also If you got some other solutions for the above issue please feel free to update the comments.